# Recover partition table previously saved with cfdisk

Tags: ubuntu, backup, data-recovery

Knowing that my external 320 GB hard drive has some problem with the connector, whenever I intend to copy something to it I first create a backup of the MBR and the partition table this way (Ubuntu 9.04):

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=HDD_mbr_20100208 count=1 bs=512  
$ sudo cfdisk /dev/sdc
```

Then in `cfdisk` I choose the `Print` option and then the `Raw` option which saves the partition table in the very same format it would have been written to disk.

Now I need to recover what I have saved. The MBR part is really simple (just change the `if` and the `of` part in the first command), but there is no an obvious way to recover the partition table in `cfdisk`. Do you know how?

I would also appreciate any suggestion on a better way to save MBR, partition table and FATs (volume is FAT32 formatted).

Thanks in advance.

Sergio.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your partition layout, your MBR restoration (`dd if=HDD_mbr_20100208 of=/dev/sdc...`) may have already done it all.  This is because the MBR and primary partition table is stored in the first 512-byte sector of the drive.  For this to work, your drive:

- must use [MBR-style partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record),
- must have no more than 4 primary partitions, AND
- must have no extended or logical partitions.

If you have an extended partition and enclosed logical partitions, you may need to translate your *cfdisk*-created partition table backup.  I don't know of any way to easily tell *fdisk* or *cfdisk* what new partition table to write -- *sfdisk* can do this easily, but the *cfdisk* raw format is not the same as what *sfdisk* reads and writes.  You can probably translate one format to the other manually.

*cfdisk*'s raw output is formatted in one of these two ways (source: [`man cfdisk`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cfdisk)):

> The *raw data format* will print the sectors that would
>   be written to disk if a write command is selected. First, the
>   primary partition table is printed, followed by the partition
>   tables associated with each logical partition. The data is printed
>   in hex byte by byte with 16 bytes per line.
>
> ...
>
> The *partition table in raw format* will print the partition table
>   ordered by partition number. It will leave out all free and unusable
>   space. The fields, from left to right, are the number of the partition,
>   the flags (in hex), the starting head, sector and cylinder, the filesystem
>   ID (in hex), the ending head, sector and cylinder, the starting sector
>   in the partition and the number of sectors in the partition. The information
>   in this table can be directly translated to the raw data format.

Comment: note: it's nearly guaranteed you're using MBR partitions, because the *fdisk* tools don't support GPT/GUID partitions.  still, the restriction is important, so i want to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

For the backup part, [here](http://www.ducea.com/2006/10/09/partition-table-backup/) are some examples. I personally use [sfdisk](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sfdisk) to backup/restore partition tables.

If you have destroyed the partition table, but did not overwrite the data, you can use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to try to restore the partition table.